# disable the selected button

Tags: html, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to disable a button which is been selected. Suppose i have 2 buttons, "ON" & "OFF".

**Now if the "ON" button is selected it shouldn't be allowed to select the "ON" button again until the "OFF button is being selected."**

```
<form action="myclass.php" method="post">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOnbutton">
            // myOnbutton is the button name
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> ON
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs myOffbutton">
            // myOffbutton is the button name
            <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> OFF
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

So the main purpose is to disable the button which is selected.
Do anyone knows how to solve this problem !
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variant [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0epg8sm/):

```
$(function () {
    var onButton = $(".btn-group .btn:eq(0)");
    var offButton = $(".btn-group .btn:eq(1)");

    onButton.on("click", function () {
        if (!onButton.is("disabled")) {
            offButton.attr("disabled", false);
            onButton.attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
    offButton.on("click", function () {
        if (!offButton.is("disabled")) {
            onButton.attr("disabled", false);
            offButton.attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @ChristoferHansen What actually doesn't work? Can you show it in jsFiddle?

Comment: my bad, it is working fine, thanks for your great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// https://jsfiddle.net/243mbpwo/2/

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var onButton = inputs[0];
var offButton = inputs[1];

onButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
});

offButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    onButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
});
```

Comment: "Off" button is enabled even if it was selected.

Comment: Correct. OP didn't specify disabling the Off button.

Comment: the off or on button is not disable after selecting, which can not solve my problem

Comment: In the jsfiddle, when I select the ON button, the ON button becomes disabled until the OFF button is clicked. Are you seeing other behavior?

Comment: @IvanSuftin in jsfiddle i have seen you can select both button at the same time :) please have a look by yourself by clicking 2 button

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Yes, I agree. You need to add the "name" attribute to both buttons as Hopfeeyy suggests. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/243mbpwo/3/

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this, if you are already using bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

Comment: @Repsesh that doesnot solve my problem, where the button can be select again which is already selected

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="on">ON</br>
  <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="off">OFF</br>
</div>
```

You don't need javascript or jQuery for this approach.